# Heroku PG thinks a column is undefined. Sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I just recently added a column via migration to my production app, and I've been getting Rollbar errors all day that I can't figure out.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column callable_phone_numbers.active does not exist
LINE 1: ...llable_phone_numbers"."phone_number_id" AS t0_r3, "callable_...
^
: SELECT "callable_phone_numbers".*, "callable_phone_numbers"."id" AS t0_r0, "callable_phone_numbers"."callable_id" AS t0_r1, "callable_phone_numbers"."callable_type" AS t0_r2, "callable_phone_numbers"."phone_number_id" AS t0_r3, "callable_phone_numbers"."active" AS t0_r4, "callable_phone_numbers"."created_at" AS t0_r5, "callable_phone_numbers"."updated_at" AS t0_r6, "phone_numbers"."id" AS t1_r0, "phone_numbers"."number" AS t1_r1, "phone_numbers"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "phone_numbers"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "phone_numbers"."label" AS t1_r4, "phone_numbers"."assigned" AS t1_r5, "phone_numbers"."account_id" AS t1_r6, "phone_numbers"."sent_messages_count" AS t1_r7, "phone_numbers"."received_messages_count" AS t1_r8, "phone_numbers"."last_sent_message_at" AS t1_r9, "phone_numbers"."last_received_message_at" AS t1_r10, "phone_numbers"."carrier_name" AS t1_r11, "phone_numbers"."carrier_type" AS t1_r12, "phone_numbers"."carrier_updated_at" AS t1_r13 FROM "callable_phone_numbers" LEFT OUTER JOIN "phone_numbers" ON "phone_numbers"."id" = "callable_phone_numbers"."phone_number_id" WHERE "phone_numbers"."disconnected" = 'f' AND "callable_phone_numbers"."callable_type" = 'Student' AND "callable_phone_numbers"."callable_id" IN (1181)
```

As you see, it's complaining that column `callable_phone_numbers.active` does not exist. I recently used a migration to remove that column from the join table and created a similar column (disconnected) on the table `phone_numbers`.

And yes, I double-checked my `rake db:migrate` on production.

The only place `.active` was used was in an association where clause on my `Student` model.

Previously it was...

```
class Student.rb < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :active_phone_numbers, -> { where callable_phone_numbers: {active: true} }, through: :callable_phone_numbers, source: :phone_number
```

...but simultaneously with the migration, the association became...

```
class Student.rb < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :active_phone_numbers, -> { where phone_numbers: {disconnected: false} }, through: :callable_phone_numbers, source: :phone_number
```

I have been unable to reproduce this error at all in development, and the error seems to reproduce itself randomly in production (load student once, app error, refresh, no error).

Is it possible that my code is getting cached oddly across dynos on Heroku? That the database has saved repeated queries? Something else odd I'm not aware of?

Comment: You may need to run `heroku restart`.  I've encountered this same behavior myself where the table columns are cached by rails, and a restart of the dynos flushed and reloaded said cache.

Comment: That seems reasonable. Though you'd think a deploy would restart things too...